# Removing All Elements From a Databases Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, cursors

I built this program and can't seem to figure out how to remove all of the elements from the database. My code is below:

```
def clear_books():
c = cursor()
with c.connection:
    for book in c.execute("SELECT * FROM books"):
        c.execute("DELETE FROM books WHERE title=?", (book[0],))
```

If anyone can figure this out I would be very grateful.

Comment: Figure *what* out?  You've posted invalid Python code, and given no indication of what problem(s) you are having with it.

Comment: The solutions below are better.  But to answer your original question. Have you looked at the value of `book`?  Are you sure that `book[0]` is the title?  Why are you even doing `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT title ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the loop and do

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM books;")
```